# c# - Auto increment in sqlite stops at number 10

Tags: c#, sqlite, auto-increment

i have a Table in sqlite database that contains the column "id" 
i use this code to auto increment this column when i press a button

```
con.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("Select MAX(id)+1 FROM Data", con);

        object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        int Amount = (obj != null && obj != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToInt32(obj) : 1;

        con.Close();

        tId.Text = Convert.ToString(Amount);
```

everything is fine until there is 10 records in the tables , then it refuses to retrieve the id number "11"

Comment: Why don't you define your ID column to have the [AUTOINCREMENT](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_autoincrement.htm) flag and forget about it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "refuse"? What happens?

Comment: when there is 10 records and i try to press the button it gets the id number "10" which is already exist @MichaelButscher

Comment: Why do you need the next `id` value? Are you using it for an insert? If so that is very poor design. As @Steve already mentioned, let the database do this for you. By using autoincrement you insert all values *except* for id which the sqllite will set for you on any new record.

Comment: Thank you two , i did that and it worked , but the other function is causing alot of errors , i'll try to change it.

Comment: Show the table definition. Are you using numbers or strings?

Comment: i'm using numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this updated code of your one :

```
con.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("Select MAX(cast(id as int))+1 FROM Data", con);

object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
int Amount = (obj != null && obj != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToInt32(obj) : 1;

con.Close();

tId.Text = Convert.ToString(Amount);
```

Comment: This is just the solution of your issue, not the good one! You should really set the 'id' column as auto incremented and let the database handle it. If you need to use it anywhere else as varchar, then you can easily convert this column to int on that time.